# Soap and Rest on same service returns status 404/endpoint not found for soap endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap, wcf-binding

I am trying to configure two endpoints for the same service one for rest that is webHttpBinding and one for soap that is wsHttpBinding. but when I hit the service for soap it gives me no endpoint found.

Here is my interface
ITicketService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITicketService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/tickets")]
    void AddTicket(Ticket ticket);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/tickets")]
    IQueryable<Ticket> GetAllTickets();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/tickets/{id}")]
    Ticket GetTicketById(string id);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/tickets/show_many?ids={ids}")]
    IQueryable<Ticket> GetSeveralTicketsById(string ids);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/tickets/{ticket_id}")]
    void UpdateTicket(Ticket ticket, string ticket_id);
}
```

Here is ticket service markup

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.TicketService" 
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" CodeBehind="TicketService.svc.cs" %>
```

Here is my actual service implementation

```
public class TicketService : ITicketService
{
    TicketManager _ticketManager = new TicketManager();
    public void AddTicket(Ticket ticket)
    {
        _ticketManager.InsertTicket(ticket);
    }

    public IQueryable<Ticket> GetAllTickets()
    {
        return _ticketManager.GetAllTickets();
    }

    public Ticket GetTicketById(string id)
    {
        int ticketId = Convert.ToInt16(id);
        return _ticketManager.GetTicketById(ticketId);
    }

    public IQueryable<Ticket> GetSeveralTicketsById(string ids)
    {
        var idList = ids.Split(',');
        List<Ticket> tickets = new List<Ticket>();
        foreach (var item in idList)
        {
            tickets.Add(GetTicketById(item));
        }
        return tickets.AsQueryable();
    }

    public void UpdateTicket(Ticket ticket, string ticket_id)
    {
        int ticketId = Convert.ToInt16(ticket_id);
        ticket.Id = ticketId;
        _ticketManager.UpdateTicket(ticket);
    }

}
```

Here is my Service Configuration (web.config)

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <!-- or WsHttpBinding -->
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding" >
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.ITicketService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint name="restTicketService" address="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.ITicketService"  behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint name="soapTicketService" address="soap" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.ITicketService" >
    </endpoint>
  </service>
  <service name="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.ITicketCommentService"  behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.ITicketCommentService"  behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.ITicketCommentService"  >
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

  </service>
  <service name="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.IUserIdentityService"  behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.IUserIdentityService"  behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.IUserIdentityService" >
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

  </service>

</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

When I go to url **http://example.com/TicketService.svc/tickets** it gives me correct data for rest endpoint

and

When I go to url **http://example.com/TicketService.svc/soap** it gives me **Endpoint not found.**

so not able to create proxy for soap service.

Thanks in advance for your time to review my question.

Comment: I think the problem may be with your markup in the .svc file.  `System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory` is for RESTful WCF, and I don't know if it will support SOAP.  Have you tried using `System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory` instead?

Comment: @Tim Yes, if I Remove System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory then it works fine for SOAP but stops working Rest. so now I will try changing it with System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Tim I did tried for "System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" but it only works for soap and REST stopped working. Do you know any factory that supposed to work for both SOAP and REST.

Comment: @Tim I have found problem. See my below Reply. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi finally I found the problem and also can't believe this silly mistake.

```
<service name="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.ITicketService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
<endpoint name="restTicketService" address="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.ITicketService"  behaviorConfiguration="web">
</endpoint>
<endpoint name="soapTicketService" address="soap" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="TicketSupportSystem.Rest.Service.ITicketService" >
</endpoint>
```

In the above code snippet Service name targets Interface ITicketService which is wrong instead it should target TicketService concrete implementation.

And also no need to mention

```
System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory
```

factory in service markup for running REST with SOAP service.